# Why won't xcodebuild use my provisioning profiles?

Tags: provisioning-profile, xcodebuild, fastlane, fastlane-match, fastlane-gym

I have a GitHub Action that builds my app and uploads it to TestFlight automatically. Ever since I added a Notification Service extension, I've been having issues with building the app. I have been using Fastlane, but I boiled the issue down to the following command:
`xcodebuild archive -scheme Yeshivat\ Torat\ Shraga -project ./Yeshivat\ Torat\ Shraga.xcodeproj`

This command works fine on my laptop, but when run in a Github Actions CI machine, it produces the following error:

```
error: "NotificationModifier" requires a provisioning profile with the App Groups feature. Select a provisioning profile in the Signing & Capabilities editor. (in target 'NotificationModifier' from project 'Yeshivat Torat Shraga')
error: "Yeshivat Torat Shraga" requires a provisioning profile with the Associated Domains, App Groups, App Attest, and Push Notifications features. Select a provisioning profile in the Signing & Capabilities editor. (in target 'Yeshivat Torat Shraga' from project 'Yeshivat Torat Shraga')
```

When using *gym*, I am specifying the correct certificates, yet I am getting the above error (also, only on the CI machine).

**My questions**

- Why does this work on my laptop, but not on the CI machine?

  - How can I set up my local environment to match the CI machine to easier debug this?
- How can I automate this process successfully (either directly with `xcodebuild`, or preferably with Fastlane)?

---

I have been struggling with this issue for the last  8 days, any help is absolutely welcome!

Comment: You need to get your provisioning profiles onto the CI machine somehow (similar to how you do it for your main project). The fastlane approach is called “match” which syncs the profiles using a storage mechanism like git repo, Google drive, or gitlab secure files.